# Where does the code belong in a Symfony2 project?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I have the following entity for the information of points on the map

```
Place
    id
    name
    latitude
    longitude
    org_id
    street
    city
```

Using the [IvoryGoogleMapBundle](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle), I would like to place these places as markers on the map, also give each marker an info window with the following information

```
[ORGANIZATION NAME]
Name:   [PLACE NAME]
Street: [PLACE STREET]
City:   [PLACE CITY]
```

I am confused now. I created a simple service, that gets a `MapBuilder` as costructor parameter, also has the `setMarkersData(dataOfPlaces)` and returns the `map instance`.

Where should I process the places data? Should I set the doctrine collection as the markers data and manipulate it inside `MapBuilder` using `Place` entity getters an setter?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "process data"?

I think you want to have paces data in you controller. So, you have to call your service from controller to get appropriate data:

```
$this->get('your_service_to_get_places')->get();
```

And in service you have to gather all the data you need. I mean if you need only 'name', 'street' and 'city' properties of Place retrieve only these fields. If you need an array - retrieve an array instead of collection.

Everything depends on your needs.